# Updating ArcGIS Online WebMap from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I have opened my WebMap in ArcGIS Pro via the project tab. I received a notification stating "click update map to replace the map in your project". I am curious as to what this will do?